# How to check multiple variable is empty or not in Puppet 4.x

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to check two or more variables is empty or not. To achieve it, I found the following way.

```
if $path {
    if $name {
          notify { "Path : ${path}": }
          notify { "Name : ${name}": }
    }
}
```

If we need to check more than two variables, How to check it out ?

Please suggest any best way to code.

Comment: In Puppet 4, only *undefined* values convert to boolean as `false`.  All other values, including empty strings, empty lists, and empty hashes convert to boolean as `true`.  Your example suggests that you actually want to determine whether the variables in question are *defined*, not whether they are empty.  Is that in fact what you want?

Comment: @JohnBollinger : Really sorry to raised a question with wrong example. I want to check whether a variable contains empty string or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to check two or more variables is empty or not.

I take you to mean that you want to determine whether *any* of several variables is an empty string.  You can use the new `reduce()` function to solve this problem.

For example, this ...

```
$is_any_empty = reduce([$one, $two, $three], false) |$memo, $entry| {
    $memo or ($entry == '')
}
```

... sets variable `$is_any_empty` to `true` if and only if at least one of the variables `$one`, `$two`, and `$three` contains an empty string, which is what you asked.

Even with your clarification, though, I suspect that's not exactly what you really want.  My best guess is that you actually want to determine whether *all* of a set of variables have values that are *non*-empty strings (as opposed to being undefined or having values that are not strings at all).  That kind of type-aware checking can be done with the help of Puppet 4's new type system:

```
$all_are_nonempty = reduce([$one, $two, $three], true) |$memo, $entry| {
    $memo and ($entry =~ String[1])
}
```

The `$entry =~ String[1]` is a boolean expression evaluating to whether the value of variable `$entry` has type `String` and is at least one character long.  Do note that it will match strings consisting of only spaces; if you don't want that then the needed mods are left as an exercise.